# MassTransit Consumer - Send from php

Tags: masstransit

I would like to specify for php developers how to Send a message (Command in the MassTransit documentation) that will be consumed by a MassTransit C# consumer.

What are the minimum requirements to ensure the message is consumed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to form the message as a correct JSON document, like this:

```
{
    "destinationAddress": "rabbitmq://localhost/input_queue",
    "headers": {},
    "message": {
        "value": "Some Value",
        "customerId": 27
    },
    "messageType": [
        "urn:message:MassTransit.Tests:ValueMessage"
    ]
}
```

These fields form the message document, not used fields do not serialise:

```
string MessageId
string CorrelationId
string ConversationId
string InitiatorId
string RequestId
string SourceAddress
string DestinationAddress
string ResponseAddress
string FaultAddress
DateTime? ExpirationTime
IDictionary<string, object> Headers
object Message
string[] MessageType
HostInfo Host
```

There is a [full article about interoperability](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/interoperability.html) in the documentation.